# LinkedIn article share looks good in preview, but image is missing in actual post

Tags: linkedin-api, share-open-graph

I am trying to share an article (or any article from this site) on LinkedIn, but the image that is specified as `og:image` never shows up in the post.
One of the articles I test this with is http://insights.ortec-finance.com/nl-nl/2018/02/05/press-release-data-analytics and I'm using the article share link based on `https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?`

When you look at the preview, it all looks like it's going to work fine:

[image: preview looks good]

But after posting the article and looking at what has been posted, the image is missing:

[image: but image is missing in the actual post]

I've read tons of reports of similar problems and tried all the remedies I could find, but it still doesn't work. What I've tried so far:

1) Made sure that all the required `og:` meta tags are present.

```
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:image" 
      content="http://insights.ortec-finance.com/-/media/OF8/data-analytics-hero-linkedin.jpg" />
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:url" 
      content="http://insights.ortec-finance.com/nl-nl/2018/02/05/press-release-data-analytics" />
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:title" 
      content="Data Analytics | Ortec Finance" />
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:description" 
      content="removed content for readability" />
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:type" 
      content="article" />
```

2) Made sure that the image meets the LinkedIn requirements (*[less than 5MB, at least 1200x600 in dimensions](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin)*).

3) Made sure the content-type of the image is set correctly in the response header.

4) Tried several other articles and they all show the same symptoms: image is displayed in preview, but not once the share is posted.

**What am I missing here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am experiencing the same - think its a major LinkedIn bug and so far they havent been able to clarify...Our developer spent +40 hrs trying to figure it out, but now we realized that it must be a LI bug...hopefully they`ll fix it soon as it has been going on for almost a week...

Comment: It seems that Linkedin has fixed the issue. It works now!